# AppWidgetProvider: having trouble with variables

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-widget, android-appwidget

I've built a widget for home screen and declared some variables in my AppWidgetProvider class. These variables are integers and booleans.

The problem that I'm having (its basically a java programming problem) is that whatever value I assign to my variables; when I delete the widget from the home screen and then later at some time I add the widget back to the home screen, the variables are still holding the values as of the last time the widget was on home screen. I declare the variables as follows:

```
public class MyWidget extends AppWidgetProvider {
    static int iPicNum = 0;
    static Boolean bClosed = false;
    ...
```

How do I reset the values of my variables every time the widget is removed from the screen and put it back on the screen again. Or if the user wishes to have more than one instances of the widget on the screen, the variables shouldn't be sharing values between them. They should be independent from each other.

Thank you
Faraz Azhar

Answer (score 1):

If I have correctly understood the problem, you need to have unique instances of this values for each widget instance.

For such behavior you need to store data in static object, divided by appWidgetId. As for me, the best way to do this, is to use static HashMap of custom objects, like this:

```
private static class MyValues{
    private final int iPicNum = 0;
    private final boolean bClosed = false;

    public MyValues(int iPicNum, boolean bClosed) {
        this.iPicNum = iPicNum;
        this.bClosed = bClosed;
    }
    public int getiPicNum() {
        return iPicNum;
    }
    public boolean isbClosed() {
        return bClosed;
    }        
}
```

In your AppWidgetProvider class:

```
private static HashMap<int,MyValues> mValues = new HashMap<int,MyValues>;
```

When you first need to save some data for widget:

```
mValues.put(appWidetId, new MyValues(iPicNum,bClosed);
```

To obtain data:

```
MyValues values = mValues.get(appWidgetId);
if (values != null){
   int iPicNum = values.getiPicNum();
   boolean bClosed = values.isbClosed();
}
```

And don't forget to clear unused data in onDeleted() method (it called, when single instanse of widget is removed from screen):

```
public void onDeleted(Context context, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    for (int appWidgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        if (appWidgetId != -1) {
            mValues.remove(appWidgetId);
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Why not override `onDeleted()` in `MyWidget` and reset your values whenever this is called (remember to call `super.onDeleted()` though).

Comment: Yes I can do that. But if the user has put two instances of my widget on his home screen, if one resets the values on its OnDeleted, the other becomes affected because the variables are declared static. I dont want to declare the variables static in the first place. Please read my comments to above reply.

Comment: All you need to do is maintain the state of appWidgetIds based upon calls to `onUpdate()` and `onDelete()`. You can maintain independent widget instance state quite easily by keying on appWidgetId.

Comment: Mark hit the nail on the head here. Each instance has a unique Id.

Answer (score 0):

The reason that the variables are sharing values is that they're declared static. In Java, when you declare a variable static, that means that there will only ever be one instance of it. Take for example a hypothetical class PolarBear. This class could have a static Color variable, set to "white". This means that everytime you ask for PolarBear.bearColor, you'll get back the color White. It's slightly more subtle than that though. You won't get a *new* object, you'll get the same object, everytime.

Comment: I dont want to use static. I'm using it because my integer 'forgets' its value when the OnReceive code completes. Everytime OnReceive runs, the value resorts back to the originally declared value. Another person has also posted a similar question on XDA forums:

Comment: If you could provide some more code, I may be able to give you a better answer as to how to improve the design. If you use static variables, you'll only ever get 1 of them, so you'll have to figure out a way to hook into the event you want to capture to "reset" the values. I do, however, have a feeling that there is an easier and more direct way to achieve what you're trying to accomplish.